# Double Server Name With PHP Global Vars

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, global-variables

I need to access my IP address (currently on the dev server) in order to create non-relative links.

I'm declaring this in the beginning of the document:

`$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];`

and when I'm echoing it in the middle of the HTML, right before the link, I'm getting my IP Address:

`XXX.XX.XX.XXX`

However, When I'm trying to set it as the base for the url for links in my navbar:

`<a href="<?=$domain;?>/index.php">Home</a>`

OR

`<a href="<? echo $domain;?>/index.php">Home</a>`

I get the IP doubled, messing up the URL:

`XXX.XX.XX.XXX/XXX.XX.XX.XXX/index.php`

I tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` And `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to no avail.

**EDIT:** `http://` / `https://` Not allowed by server, currently have no access to server config.

**EDIT 2:** *Solution:* `$domain = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `http://` (or `https://`) at the beginning of your links, to make them absolute

Probably your links are ok, but the browser understands them as relative links.

Comment: Not allowed by server.

Comment: What do you mean? Your links should look like this on generated html: `<a href="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.php">Home</a>`, you don't need special permissions on the server to do that.

Comment: But they don't. and that's why I'm positng. When I'm trying to include the http://, the server throws an error.